# Можно ли узнать какая ширина в текста внутри тега?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть к примеру обычный список состоящий из "li" в каждом "li" есть текст. Можно ли сделать скриптом брать ширину которую занимает текст з li ?

Пробовал брать ширину с каждого тега li но ширину текста внутри тега не получается.

Пример списка:

```
 <ul>
   <li>ssssssssssssss</li>
 <ul>
```

Вот так пытался взять ширину :

```
    var widthListPr = 0;
  $('ul > li').each(function(){widthListPr = widthListPr + $(this).width() });
    console.log(widthListPr);
```

Comment: _Вот так пытался взять ширину_ - и что не получилось?

Comment: @ Grundy, берется ширина точно не текста внутри тега , а  всего  тега. Например мне из примера выше выдавало 2000px. А мне нужно как-то получить ширину текста внутри тега.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо текст обернуть в "ничего не значащий элемент". В `span` самое разумное. И размер этого `span` и выяснять.

Предлагаю такой вариант:
HTML состоит из нескольких `LI` с содержимым разной длины. Проходим по каждому, оборачиваем в `span`, вычисляем длину и выводим результат в `div.output`.

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  
  var orig = $(this).html();
  var wraped = '<span>' + orig + '</span>';
  $(this).html(wraped);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first-child').width();

  $('.output').html($('.output').html() + 'текст "' + $(this).html() + '" длиной ' + width + '<br />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>вот это текст 1</li>
  <li>а тут текст 2</li>
  <li>ткст 3</li>
  <li>ну и в конец офигительный текст 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Вариант от @cyadvert](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491153/186999), но с использованием функций: [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/), [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [toArray](http://api.jquery.com/toarray/)
А также с использованием [String Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) из ES6

```js
$('.output').html(
  $('li').wrapInner('<span></span>').find('span').map(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return `текст "${$this.html()}" длиной ${$this.width()}`;
  }).toArray().join('<br/>')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>вот это текст 1</li>
  <li>а тут текст 2</li>
  <li>ткст 3</li>
  <li>ну и в конец офигительный текст 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

создаём инлайновый элемент и прогоняем тексты измеряя ширину элемента и никаких оборачиваний, другой вариант присвоить всем нужным элементам display: "inline" собрать размер и вернуть прежний css. ниже в примере первый вариант.

```js
   $(function() {
     var c = $("li"),
       a = $("<li/>", {
         css: {
           display: "inline"
         }
       }).appendTo("body");
     $(".output").html($.map(c, function(b) {
       return b.textContent + "=>" + a.text(b.textContent).width() + "<br>"
     }));
     a.remove()
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>вот это текст 1</li>
  <li>а тут текст 2</li>
  <li>ткст 3</li>
  <li>ну и в конец офигительный текст 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="output"></div>
```